# How to add Emoji plugin to CKEditor used in ZK framework?

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, zk, backoffice, zk-grid

I have a requirement where my **ZK wysiwyg toolbar** needs to provide an option of adding an Emoji.

I checked and found that there is a Emoji plugin already shipped with CKEditor but I am unable to enable it on ZK editor.

I already tried to add below in to configuration file, but it doesn't work.

```
config.toolbar_EmojiOnly = [
    ['emoji']
];
```

Can anyone please help?

Please note -  I don't want to use Smiley plugin. I want to use Emoji plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is three things to do to add plugins CKEditor for a ZK application.
1: download all of the plugin files, including the dependencies for the plugin that you are trying to install.
For the emoji plugin, you will need at least the following plugins:

```
- ajax
- autocomplete
- emoji
- floatpanel
- panelbutton
- textmatch
- textwatcher
- xml
```

You can download these from the official CKEditor website

2: deploy your plugins into the proper folder
ZK's CKEditor plugins are located under [classpath]/web/js/ckez/ext/CKeditor/plugins
A standard deployment would be at [application root]/src/main/resources/web/js/ckez/ext/CKeditor/plugins
Your deployment should look like:

```
- [root]/src/main/resources/web/js/ckez/ext/CKeditor/plugins/ajax/plugin.js
- [root]/src/main/resources/web/js/ckez/ext/CKeditor/plugins/emoji/plugin.js
- [root]/src/main/resources/web/js/ckez/ext/CKeditor/plugins/emoji/assets/...
etc.
```

3: actually adding the plugin to your ckeditor instance.
The standard way would be to use a custom config file such as:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
    config.extraPlugins = 'emoji';
};
```

and you would declare your config such as:

```
<ckeditor customConfigurationsPath="/path/to/config.js"/>
```

Comment: Thanks @MDuchemin - I earlier tried to add this plugin to ckez.jar directly with winrar. I knew it wasn't the right way but wanted to check if it works. I will give it a try with your inputs and get back to you. Thanks once again.